# Can't find where the error is in this JavaScript code. Not very familliar with 'class' syntax

Tags: javascript, oop, debugging, ecmascript-6

This is the code. It is an assignment from a random stranger that asked me to solve it for him since he saw a post of mine on IG.

```
// Player class
class Player {
  constructor(name, strength = 2, weapons) {
    this.name = name;
    this.health = 10;
    this.strength = strength;
    this.weapons = [...weapons];
  }

  applyDamage(int) {
    this.health -= int;
  }

  isAlive() {
    return this.health > 0;
  }

  attackWith() {
    let randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8);
    return this.weapons[randomNum];
  }
}

// Weapon class

class Weapon {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.damage = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 5);
  }

  attack(player, enemy) {
    if (player.isAlive() && player.isAlive()) {
      let dmg = player.strength * this.damage;
      enemy.applyDamage(dmg);
      if (!enemy.isAlive()) {
        return;
      } else {
        enemy.attack(player);
      }
    }
  }
}

// Enemy class

class Enemy {
  constructor(name = "Enemy", health = 5, strength = 2) {
    this.name = name;
    this.health = health;
    this.strength = strength;
  }

  applyDamage(int) {
    this.health -= int;
  }

  isAlive() {
    return this.health > 0;
  }

  attack(player) {
    player.applyDamage(this.strength);
  }
}

// BattleSimulation class

class BattleSimulation {
  constructor() {
    this.players = [];
    this.enemies = [];
  }

  createEnemies() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 20; i += 1) {
      this.enemies[i] = new Enemy();
    }
  }

  createPlayers() {
    // Weapons
    let pencil = new Weapon("Pencil");
    let book = new Weapon("Book");
    let screwdriver = new Weapon("Screwdriver");
    let theOneRing = new Weapon("Sauron's Ring");
    let mustardGass = new Weapon("Mustard Gass");
    let bigBoy = new Weapon("A Nuke");
    let love = new Weapon("Power of Love");
    let theForce = new Weapon("The Force");

    let weaponsCache = [
      pencil,
      book,
      screwdriver,
      theOneRing,
      mustardGass,
      bigBoy,
      love,
      theForce
    ];

    // Players
    let luke = new Player("Luke", 5, weaponsCache);
    let baldingCoder = new Player("DraciVik", 10, weaponsCache);
    let trump = new Player("Trump", 1, weaponsCache);
    let kikiMakarena = new Player("Kiki Makarena", 5, weaponsCache);
    let johnWick = new Player("John Wick", 2, weaponsCache);

    this.players = [luke, baldingCoder, trump, kikiMakarena, johnWick];
  }

  run() {
    console.log("Simulating Battle");
    this.createEnemies();
    this.createPlayers();

    while (this.players.length !== 0 || this.enemies.length !== 0) {
      let randomPlayerIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.players.length);
      let randomPlayer = this.players[randomPlayerIndex];
      let randomEnemyIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.enemies.length);
      let randomEnemy = this.enemies[randomEnemyIndex];
      let weapon = randomPlayer.attackWith();
      weapon.attack(randomPlayer, randomEnemy);
      if (!randomPlayer.isAlive()) {
        this.players.splice(randomPlayerIndex, 1);
      }
      if (!randomEnemy.isAlive()) {
        this.enemies.splice(randomEnemyIndex, 1);
      }
    }
    console.log(this.players);
    if (this.players.length > 0) {
      return "Congratulations, you have defeated Scarlet Byle";
    }
    return "Sorry, Scarlet Byle has defeated you and conquered the free world";
  }
}

let battle = new BattleSimulation();
battle.run();
```

Anyone can see where the error is? I get a return error `'enemy.applyDamage(dmg)'` is undefined.

What is this error that I need more writing than just code? Should I spam some letters?

Comment: *I get a return error 'enemy.applyDamage(dmg)' is undefined.* ... can you show the EXACT error, as that doesn't make sense, since nowhere in your code are you trying to do anything with the result of calling that function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug here is actually just in the condition of your `while` loop:

`while(this.players.length !== 0 || this.enemies.length !== 0)`

Your condition says to loop while there is at least one player OR there is at least one enemy. So as long as ONE of the arrays is not empty, it will continue to loop.

But when you first create `this.players` and `this.enemies`, they start at different sizes. Then when you remove one entry from each array, eventually one of the arrays is empty before the other.

Then your code has `var randomEnemyIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.enemies.length);` which will evaluate to 0 when the array is empty. And when you do `this.enemies[0]`, it returns undefined. When `undefined` is passed into `weapon.attack` like `weapon.attack(randomPlayer, undefined)`, then it tries to call `applyDamage(dmg)` on the `undefined`, which throws your exception.

If you modify your code to have the following console logs, you will see the issue:

```
    while (this.players.length !== 0 || this.enemies.length !== 0) {

      console.log("PLAYERS: " + this.players.length.toString());
      console.log("ENEMIES: " + this.enemies.length.toString());

      ...
```

You will see:

```
'Simulating Battle'
'PLAYERS: 5'
'ENEMIES: 20'
'PLAYERS: 5'
'ENEMIES: 20'
'PLAYERS: 5'
[...]
'PLAYERS: 4'
'ENEMIES: 1'
'PLAYERS: 4'
'ENEMIES: 0'
error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'applyDamage' of undefined
```

So to fix this, you'll need to either change your conditional to this:

`while (this.players.length !== 0 && this.enemies.length !== 0) {`

Or you'll need to start both arrays off at the same size.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer was perfectly explained and showed where my error is. I salute you!